# Mongodb DB not getting initialised in Next.Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am trying to connect to the mongo Db using Next.Js. I am setting the db while initialising the application. However when I do getDb in another page, it is failing.

`mongo.ts`

```
import { MongoClient, Db, ServerApiVersion } from "mongodb";

let isConnected: boolean = false;
const uri: string = process.env.MONGODB_URI as string;
// const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
//   // useNewUrlParser: true,
//   // useUnifiedTopology: true,
// });

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  },
});

let db: Db | null = null;

async function connect(): Promise<void> {
  if (!isConnected) {
    await client.connect();
    db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE);
    isConnected = true;
    console.log(
      "Connected successfully to MongoDB server",
      getDb().databaseName,
    );
  }
}

function getDb(): Db {
  if (!db) {
    throw new Error(
      "Database not initialized. Did you forget to call connect first?",
    );
  }
  return db;
}

async function close(): Promise<void> {
  await client.close();
}

export { connect, getDb, close };
```

`index.tsx`

```
import { connect } from "@/config/mongo";
.
.
.

export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  try {
    await connect();
    return { props: {} };
  } catch (error: any) {
    return { props: { error: error.message } };
  }
}
```

`apply.tsx`

```
import { getDb } from "@/config/mongo";
.
.
.
export async function getServerSideProps(context: NextPageContext) {
  console.log(
    "Inside getServerSideProps of apply.tsx and database connected is ",
    getDb(),
  );
```

ERROR:

```
error - config/mongo.ts (35:10) @ getDb
error - Error: Database not initialized. Did you forget to call connect first?
    at getDb (webpack-internal:///./config/mongo.ts:35:15)
```

Comment: Is the `getServerSideProps` function from index.tsx call anywhere?

Comment: Actually the issue is `import {  getApplicationsFromDb, updateApplicationStatusInDb } from "@/lib/database";` which is called on clicking the button `onClick={() => handleAcceptCompanyIssuance(application)}` But since db updation code is on server side, it is throwing the above errors.